# Sitecore GetIdFromConfig with unicode text

Tags: c#, unicode, sitecore, sitecore7, getid3

I use Sitecore 7 and in the code I see this line

```
 public static ID HelpLinks
    {
        get { return GetIdFromConfig("aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks"); }
    }
```

Developer define this line with this function

```
 static ID GetIdFromConfig(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ID(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting(key));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn(String.Format("GetIdFromConfig (key='{0}'): not found ", key), ex, "aed.Classes.ConfigID");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I wonder how it define the

```
aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks
```

In order to get Sitecore unique ID and use it in other templates.
is any one know how it define?

Comment: Do you ask StackOverflow to ready this code for you and tell you what it does?

Comment: No I just want to know how define the unicode text like  aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks  in sitecore

Comment: What do you want achieve exactly? It's hard to understand your question

Comment: in this code  public static ID HelpLinks
    {
        get { return GetIdFromConfig("aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks"); }
    }   how the developer define  aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks that get page uniqe ID.

Comment: aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks thats give uniqe ID of page like that {4CDB8F14-8D48-4A6E-B334-6D6C58C9C821} and then I use it.

Comment: I found the solution I need to define in in idsetting.config and then use it

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in settings section in configs (either web.config or some include file from Include folder for your solution) you need to define that key with that name.

Should have something like this:

```
<sitecore>
  <settings>
    <setting name="aer.ProductDetails.HelpLinks" value="sitecoreID" />
  </settings>
</sitecore>
```

where sitecoreID is an Sitecore ID format like `{DE3A698F-1D7F-4C43-B797-162C5811E270}`